# Como especificar valores pro meu eixo x usando o matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Não estou conseguindo especificar valores pro meu eixo x, usando o matplotlib.pyplot.

Em algumas imagens o `chart.xticks(years)` resolve o problema, mas parece que quando o conjunto de valores do eixo x é pequeno demais, ele utiliza valores padrões [0,1,2,...,N]

Um caso que funciona:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um caso que não funciona:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código até então:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as chart
from matplotlib import lines

   # Settings
    chart.title(file_name)
    chart.xlabel('Years')
    chart.ylabel('Committers/Contributions')
    chart.ylim([0,highest_value + 100])
    chart.xlim(first_year,2017)

    # Values
    committer_line = chart.plot(committers_dict.keys(),committers_dict.values(),'r',label='Committer')
    contribution_line = chart.plot(contributions_dict.keys(),contributions_dict.values(),'b--',label='Contribution')
    years = list(range(first_year,2017))
    chart.xticks(years)

    # Legend
    chart.legend()

    # Show/Save
    chart.savefig(images_path + file_name.replace('.txt','-commiter-contribution.eps'), format='eps')
    chart.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os valores do matplotlib estão correctos simplesmente estao em notação cientifica. É possivel desligar a notação cientifica mas poderá dar origem a outros problemas (como teres texto sobreposto). Uma solução mais definitiva é indicares as strings das tuas labels (nos ticks), bem como posições (e eu sugiro rotação). Uma boa solução é:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as chart
from matplotlib import lines
import random

# dados gerados para esta soluçao
first_year = 2011
x1 = range(first_year,2017+1)
y1 = [random.randint(0,1100) for i in range(len(x1))]
y2 = [random.randint(0,1100) for i in range(len(x1))]
highest_value = max([max(y1),max(y2)])
file_name = 'Titulo'

# Settings
chart.title(file_name)
chart.xlabel('Years')
chart.ylabel('Committers/Contributions')
chart.ylim([0,highest_value + 100])
chart.xlim(first_year,2017)

# Values
committer_line = chart.plot(x1,y1,'r',label='Committer')
contribution_line = chart.plot(x1,y2,'b--',label='Contribution')
years = list(range(first_year,2017))
chart.xticks(years,[str(i) for i in years],rotation=45) # Usa isto para definires as tuas labels

# Legend
chart.legend()

# Show/Save
#chart.savefig(images_path + file_name.replace('.txt','-commiter-contribution.eps'), format='eps')
chart.show()
```

, que dá origem a este gráfico:

[image: Mudar as labels dos ticks]

Para responder directamente à tua questão (se não quiseres utilizar a sugestão acima) para desligares a notação cientifica podes fazer:

```
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
```

, em que o `ax` poderia ser construido da seguinte maneira (entre outras):

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

Terias também de chamar o teu `plot` a partir do `ax`.